# Event Receiver Item Updating Datasheet view Problem

Tags: event-handlers

I've got a list that is being displayed and edited in datasheet view and now I need to ensure that users cant edit a column if there already is a value, but if the column is empty they should be able to edit the column.

I have never worked with event receivers before so for the time I am stuck. Right now a user cant edit/delete a column value but neither add a value if the column is empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemUpdating(properties);

        SPWeb currentWeb = properties.OpenWeb();
        {
            if (currentWeb.CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin == false)
            {
                if (properties.ListItem["Column"] != null)
                {
                    properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
                    properties.ErrorMessage = "blabla";
                    properties.Cancel = true;
                }
                else if(properties.ListItem["Column"] == null
                {
                properties.Cancel = false;
                properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.Continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
            if (properties.ListItem["Column"] != null)
            {
                properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
                properties.ErrorMessage = "blabla";
                properties.Cancel = true;
            }
            else if(properties.ListItem["Column"] == null
            {
            properties.Cancel = false;
            properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.Continue;
            }
```

with this

```
            string columnValue = properties.ListItem["Column"] == null ? null : properties.ListItem["Column"].ToString()
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnValue))
            {
                properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
                properties.ErrorMessage = "blabla";
                properties.Cancel = true;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will test it asap!

As for the using statement when working with event receivers to prevent memory leaks, i am following MSDNs best practice for Instantiating an SPSite object, please see:

[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee724407.ASPX)

Thanks again

Comment: You are right, there is no memory leak in this case.

Comment: Naim, i did replace my code, but it still throws error when trying to enter a value to the empty column. What is the difference between my old code and yours?

Comment: Your code checks for null only.My code checks for null and empty. Also there is no need to set properties.Cancel to FALSE so you don't need ELSE IF in your code. What type is the column you are checking?

Comment: It is a lookup column that gets the name of employees from another list as single text.

Comment: Does the event receiver works properly with a standard view? If yes then check this about a hotfix (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84928b6d-440b-4018-a140-4956f46720ec/list-datasheet-view-itemupdating-cancel-event-end-user-error-message-support)

Comment: Indeed it does work and throw error if i try to edit/update the column. I can't believe i've missed about the datasheet hotfix! Case closed, thanks for your help!